# I want to copy rows if it contains certain text to another sheet using VBA

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a macro that copies a row if a cell in that row contain text (For ex: Mumbai, Delhi, Pune, Hyd, Chennai like 17 Text searches are there and they are constant and available in column C. It's not necessary that i will receive data for all 17 text searches every time. Some times i receive 10 text searches data and some time more.

For example if there are 1000 rows but only few contains text(Mumbai, Delhi, Hyd etc) in column C. I want to copy those rows and paste them into "Sheet2" I was using the below code. however it is copying only two search strings from column C. My requirement is the code should search for all 17 textsearches and copy the available textsearchs rows referencing column C to next sheet/Sheet2. Also i want to copy data of columns a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i to Sheet2.

```
Sub testPasteinSh2Bis()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range
 Dim rngCopy As Range, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long
 Dim strSearch1 As String, strSearch2 As String
 
 'a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, l 'columns to be copied
 strSearch1 = "Mumbai" 'or combo value...
 strSearch2 = "Delhi"  'or something else...
 Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'use here your worksheet
 Set sh2 = sh1.Next 'use here your sheet
 lastR1 = sh1.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 Set rng = sh1.Range("C2:C" & lastR1)
 For Each cel In rng.cells
    If cel.Value = strSearch1 Or cel.Value = strSearch2 Then
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = sh1.Range(sh1.Range("A" & cel.Row & ":D" & cel.Row).Address & "," & _
                   sh1.Range("F" & cel.Row & ":I" & cel.Row).Address & "," & sh1.Range("L" & cel.Row).Address)
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, sh1.Range(sh1.Range("A" & cel.Row & ":D" & cel.Row).Address & "," & _
                   sh1.Range("F" & cel.Row & ":I" & cel.Row).Address & "," & sh1.Range("L" & cel.Row).Address))
        End If
    End If
 Next
 If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngCopy.Copy Destination:=sh2.cells(lastR2, 1)
 End If
End Sub
```

Could someone please guide me. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you can add more "or" statements, you are not limited to just 2.

Comment: @Davesexcel yes i can able to add more "Or" statements and it worked out. Thank you! Can you please suggest me if i wnat to paste data into a new workbook. I tried but receiving complie error.